# Definition of the circulation of a vector field and line integral of a scalar field : is there a connexion between them?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, and $\Gamma=\{\gamma (t)=(\gamma _1(t),...,\gamma _n(t))\mid t\in [a,b]\}$ then $$\int_\Gamma fd\gamma =\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\|\gamma '(t)\|dt.$$

If $F:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, $F=(F_1,...,F_n)$ then $$\int_\Gamma F\cdot d\gamma =\int_a^b F(\gamma (t))\cdot \gamma '(t)dt.\tag{E}$$

---

Now, I would like to say :
$$\int_\Gamma F\cdot d\gamma =\int_\Gamma\sum_{i=1}^n F_id\gamma _i=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_a^b F_i(\gamma _i(t))\|\gamma _i'(t)\|dt,\tag{F}$$
but I don't really find $(E)$. So is there a way to find $(E)$ from $(F)$ ? It should be, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $(\gamma,\phi)$ is a regular curve with $\phi:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^3$, with $\phi\in C^1$ and $\phi([a,b])=\gamma$, the integral of a differential form $\omega=\sum a_i dx_i$ along $\gamma$ is (with $F=(a_1,a_2,a_3$)):
$$\int_\gamma\omega:=\int_a^b \sum_{i=0}^3 F_i(\phi(t))\phi_i'(t)dt=\int_a^b \langle F(\phi(t),\phi'(t)\rangle dt=\int_a^b\langle F(\phi(t)),\frac{\phi'(t)}{||\phi'(t)||}\rangle||\phi'(t)||dt=\int_a^b \langle F(\phi(t),T(t)\rangle ds$$

where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $T(t)=\frac{\phi'(t)}{||\phi'(t)||}$ and $ds=||\phi'(t)||dt$ is the curvilinear abscissa's differential. This is the correct formal procedure to find the integral of the 2nd kind.

Edit: forgot the i-th component in F in the first equality

Comment: Thank you but why may way of doing in (F) doesn't work ? Because it looks to be very natural to do like I did in (F) but I don't understand why is wrong

Comment: because implicitly when you write $F\cdot d\gamma$ you are doing $F\cdot T(t)d\gamma$ as I point out in the last equation.